# How to check palindrome or not with data type number or string

Tags: python

I made a function for string or number if the data is a palindrome or not.

What I want is:

If I insert `is_palindrome('Katak') # return true`

```
is_palindrome('katak') # return true
```

but how to put `is_palindrome(696)` to return `True`.

I made this code:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    if str(word.lower()) == str(word.lower()[::-1]):
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

but if I insert `is_palindrome(696)` then it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brambang\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Return statements.py", line 45, in <module>
    is_palindrome(696)
  File "C:\Users\Brambang\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Return statements.py", line 39, in is_palindrome
    if str(word.lower()) == str(word.lower()[::-1]):
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Change parenthesis order? `str(word).lower()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `str.lower()` on an `int` hence the error:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    if str(word).lower() == str(word).lower()[::-1]:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

If you are interested in further improvements in readability, I would write the function like this:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    return str(word).lower() == str(word).lower()[::-1]

print(is_palindrome('katak'))
print(is_palindrome(696))
```

Output:

```
True
True
```